# French terminology for the space industry

Tags: terminology

I am interested to know if there is some consolidated resource for **matching** space and satellite **terminology** **between** **English** and **French**.

Examples of words to translate include: Orbital Elements, Space Weather, Satellite Operations, Uplink / Downlink, Surface Discharge, etc..

I would like to not use Google Translate if there is already some standard terms that I am not aware of.

I am already familiar with the [IATE dictionary](https://iate.europa.eu/home) multi-language translations, but I am interested to know if there are translations more specific to the space industry.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just barely related: [what are these circular spots on the Ariane V SRB nozzles?](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37966/195)

Comment: Interesting question. There were a number of native French speaking astronauts in the shuttle program - Perrin, Chrétien, Payette - but I don't remember any training documents in French for them. Sadly I suspect they were expected to use English.

Comment: Thank you @russel, it is amazing how the Solid Rocket Booster translates to "Powder-based Acceleration Stage". This is the type of matching that I am interested in capturing. Every bit helps, Thank you!

Comment: I understand @OrganicMarble, thank you for the trivia insight!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some resources exist to assist with this effort:

1. (Book) ***Dictionnaire de l'aeronautique et de l'espace francais - anglais***
   ISBN-10 : 0828811695
   ISBN-13 : 978-0828811699
   Publisher : French & European Pubns (June 1, 2005)
   Editor: Henri Goursau

[Amazon link to purchase](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0828811695)

2. (Book-French only) **Dictionnaire de l'Astronomie et de l'Espace**
   Authors: Philippe de La Cotardière, Jean-Pierre Penot
   Editor: Larousse
   ISBN: 2-03-720332-2

[Amazon link to purchase](https://www.amazon.ca/Dict-astronomie-Espace-PHILIPPE-COTARDIERE/dp/2037203322)

This book is only in French, so the understanding/translation of terms requires some partial knowledge of French to identify the exact terms in English by "extrapolation".

3. (Webpage): The ***[Interactive Terminology for Europe IATE Dictionary](https://iate.europa.eu/home)***, an effort of the European Union to translate terms in all European languages.
4. (Webpage) ***[Astronautics Vocabulary](https://www.asc-csa.gc.ca/eng/resources/vocabulary/default.asp?like=A)***, provided by the Canadian Space Agency. A convenient, alphabetically sorted list of various terms.

I hope the above can be useful to someone! Manny